# MathJax ignores a `\tag` in an `{equation}` containing a `{split}`

Tags: bug, mathjax

The following snippet, when compiled as part of a LaTeX document with appropriate packages loaded, would produce a numbered (well, `\tag`ged) equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\begin{split}
4 & = 2\cdot2 \\ & = (1 + 1)(1 + 1) \\ & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

(In case you think, as I briefly suspected, that it's just the numbering automatically provided by `{equation}`, it doesn't seem to be; it works just as well if you use `\tag{I am not a number}` instead of `\tag{1}`.)  However, under MathJax, it does not.

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\begin{split}
4 & = 2\cdot2 \\ & = (1 + 1)(1 + 1) \\ & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The same thing seems to happen if the inner environment is, say, `{aligned}`.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in version 2.7.8 of MathJax, but StackExchange is still using version 2.7.5 (and the highest version 2 release is 2.7.9).  I understand not moving to version 3, but I don't know why SE won't update to 2.7.9.